# Html table td width by vertical text?

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    

<div class="row">                  
    <table height="200"  class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight" >
        <tbody>
            <tr height="20">
                <td rowspan="3" width="4%" style="vertical-align: middle;"><p style="transform: rotate(270deg);white-space: nowrap;">1.I have here some long title</p></td>
                <td colspan="6" rowspan="3" width="384" >Here i have some text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="20">
            </tr>
            <tr height="20">
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that i want to have an vertical text and i used **transform: rotate(270deg)** but it makes the width of **`<td>`** not functionable. I wan to have an small one. Like:

[Look here i have a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uaQg.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `writing-mode` and then rotate the text 180degrees.

> The writing-mode CSS property defines whether lines of text are laid out horizontally or vertically, as well as the direction in which blocks progress.
>
> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)

```css
p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <table height="200" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight">
    <tbody>
      <tr height="20">
        <td rowspan="3">
          <p>1.I have here some long title</p>
        </td>
        <td colspan="6" rowspan="3" width="384">Here i have some text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr height="20">
      </tr>
      <tr height="20">
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
p {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    

<div class="row">                  
    <table height="200"  class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight" >
        <tbody>
            <tr height="20">
                <td rowspan="3" width="4%" style="vertical-align: middle;padding: 2rem;"><p>1.I have here some long title</p></td>
                <td colspan="6" rowspan="3" width="384" >Here i have some text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="20">
            </tr>
            <tr height="20">
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thx but i need an vertical text like in my snippet not an **vertical-align** . i need something like **transform: rotate(270deg)**

Answer (score 0):

//screenshot is given below

1.I have here some long title.

Here i have some textHere i have some text

```
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="3" >
<p style="transform: rotate(270deg);"><span style="word-wrap: break-word;  white-space: nowrap; color: red;">1.I have here some long title</span></p>
</td>
<td colspan="6" rowspan="3" width="384"><p style="max-width:40px;">Here i have some text. Here I have some text</p></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="3">
<p style="transform: rotate(270deg);"><span style="word-wrap: break-word;  white-space: nowrap; color: red;">1.I have here some long title</span></p>
</td>
<td colspan="6" rowspan="3" width="384"><p style="max-width:40px;">Here i have some text. Here I have some text</p></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>`enter code here`
</div>[![screenshot below][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lfdT.png
```

Comment: thx for answer but you have the same problem as i have. look in your picture. Look at my question, it was about the width. And look in my picture what i need.